# string quoting issues in doctests

Tags: python, testing, doctest

When I run doctests on different Python versions (2.5 vs 2.6) and different plattforms (FreeBSD vs Mac OS) strings get quoted differently:

```
Failed example:
    decode('{"created_by":"test","guid":123,"num":5.00}')
Expected:
    {'guid': 123, 'num': Decimal("5.00"), 'created_by': 'test'}
Got:
    {'guid': 123, 'num': Decimal('5.00'), 'created_by': 'test'}
```

So on one box repr(decimal.Decimal('5.00')) results in 'Decimal("5.00")' on the other in "Decimal('5.00')". Is there any way to get arround the issue withyout creating more compliated test logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually because the `decimal` module's source code has changed: In python 2.4 and python2.5 the `decimal.Decimal.__repr__` function contains:

```
return 'Decimal("%s")' % str(self)
```

whereas in python2.6 it contains:

```
return "Decimal('%s')" % str(self)
```

So in this case the best thing to do is just to print out `str()` of the result and check the type separately if necessary...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately I also have a lot dictionaries as return value, so just comparing str() will not work.

I edited ,y question accordingly.

Comment: Ah, in that case, it may be best for you to look at actual unittests not just doctests... doctests get too complicated when you're dealing with complexities like this IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Following the hits by D[avid Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120398/david-fraser) i found [this suggestion](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-July/081420.html) by Raymond Hettinger on the Python mailinglist.

I now use something like this:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[:2] <= (2, 5):
    # ugly monkeypatch to make doctests work. For the reasons see
    # See http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-July/081420.html
    # It can go away once all our boxes run python > 2.5
    decimal.Decimal.__repr__ = lambda s: "Decimal('%s')" % str(s)
```